# Changing Custom Field Length has no effect

Tags: custom-object, custom-field

I've increased a Text Field Length from 15 to 255 yet every time I try to enter text into the field I get an error that maxlength=15. Another custom field on the same object works fine. The Setup of the object says it is 255 so I am utterly confused.

Comment: is there any validation rule / trigger doing the length check on that field ?

Comment: There are no validation rules on this custom object or field, and the trigger code does not actively mention a length of 15.

Comment: I checked again, we have no validation rules, no triggers on the custom object either. I checked all of our Apex Classes and neither length nor 15 are mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution (finally) was that there was also a CustomSetting where this information was being saved. It had it's own custom fields, named the exact same thing and I was able to modify their length to 255 and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score -2):

Then there is Validation Rules or Trigger or Apex Classes which is throwing the error. Please check with all of them.

Comment: While Vamsi Krishna has suggested that the issue may be validation or a trigger, and indeed, it seems likely, the original poster (OP) of the question hasn't confirmed it. I think this answer is a bit early, and doesn't really contain a solution to OP's problem. I feel that this answer would be better if you included information about **how to fix** the problem **rather than just how to find** if this is the problem. -1 from me.